# Mono.Data.Sqlite "Unable to open the database file" with relative path

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono

I'm trying to get Mono.Data.Sqlite to run on my Windows computer (and on a Ubuntu server). This syntax successfully accesses the data is I specify an absolute path. With a relative path, however, I get "Unable to open the database file". I tried every syntax with Data Source and URI, with no success.

```
using (var db = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=App_Data\MyDatabase.db;Version=3;")) {}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Of course I could do a Server.MapPath to get an absolute path, but this can't be the right way to do this.

Comment: What is your current working path? (`System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`) Is it the root of `App_Data\MyDatabase.db`?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express"

Comment: Since you are using IIS Express, use `IApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath` as your base path (your `IApplicationEnvironment` is supplied as a param to `Startup`

Comment: and what if I want to put the connection string in Web.config?

Comment: Now I understand what |DataDirectory| is for. It wasn't working at first, but now I'm trying it again and it works! @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.db;Version=3;"

Comment: It's working on Windows, but on the Ubuntu server, I now get again "Unable to open the database file". What else am I missing?